# How to print the exit code of the last executed application in a Windows batch file?

Tags: windows, shell, batch-file

I have a Unix shell script with the following code, which I want to turn into a Windows batch file:

```
./test.sh some arguments here

export a=$?
echo "RETURN CODE FROM UpgradeR16 = $a"
```

I've already rewritten `test.sh` into `test.bat`, but I'm not sure what the `export` and `echo` are doing here. How do I write the equivalent code in a Windows .bat file?

Comment: Instead of pasting the code, which obviously doesn't say a thing to most batch-file language experts, you should have thought of a clear and specific question like "how to print an exit code in a batch file" and google it. Normally you would find an answer in a matter of seconds or minutes.

Comment: Is a duplicate but the duplicate has no answer :D

Comment: ...and the duplicate has now been automatically deleted.

Answer (score 1):

If by `$?` is ment to be the return value of the last execution then this needs to be replaced with `%ERRORLEVEL%` in a windows batch file.

So you could just use `echo "RETURN CODE FROM Upgrade16 = %ERRORLEVEL%"`